# How can I set up a custom domain or URL for my Google Form?

Tags: google-forms

I am trying to create a Google Form for a project and I was wondering if it is possible to have a custom domain or URL for the form. I know that the default URL for a Google Form is something like `forms.google.com/form/xyz`, but I was hoping to have something like `myproject.com/form` instead. Is this possible, and if so, how can I set it up?

Any help or guidance on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to have a custom URL. Google provides a way of shortening the URL but it's still not in a readable format. But it seems like you are looking for a way to embed or integrate google forms into another domain with a custom URL. There are great solutions already available for it. I would recommend you to check out [BetterCollected](https://bettercollected.com/). They not only provide the possibility of adding a custom URL to your forms, but if you work in an organization, you can create custom workspaces. You can even have a custom domain if you intend to without any hassles.

Comment: Looks interesting but seems it is still in development

Answer (score 1):

Google Form as of time of writing does not support customizing the URL. So, you'll need to find some external service for customizing the URL. Most of the services I found embedded the form and let user customize the URL of embedded page. This seems to be what Better Collected mentioned on one of the answer is doing.

Further, I found a blog article on setting custom URL for Google. I'm linking it here as it seems like a step by step guide and might be useful to people looking for details.
https://bettercollected.com/custom-url-for-google-forms/